# using multiple JPA Entity manager with single database

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have the following setup,
Client <--> Web <--> Multiple Data Services with Hibernate (in different server) <--> Database

Is this setup possible? (multiple Hibernate instances for single DB). If so if I enable cache at Hibernate side, how the correct data will be retrieved? Because in one of the server the old data might be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. We have an application using the same mechanism. I'm not sure whether hibernates manages a distributed cache (like oracle coherence). But for our application we have implemented a distributed cache to manage this scenario.

Comment: JBoss infinispan supports remote caching. Will try that. Thx